# Flutter Navigation doesn't pop Navigator stack on back press

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm using `Navigator` for named routes to switch pages on screen with a `BottomNavigationBar`. On Page 3, I can navigate to Page 4 by `NavigationKey.currentState.pushNamed(Page4Route)`.

On Page 4, I'm able to navigate back to Page 3 by calling `NavigationKey.currentState.pop`, but pressing the back button of the device closes the app instead. Any idea why the back button doesn't pop the current screen on the Navigation stack? How can I handle this better?

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Navigator(
      key: navigationKey,
      initialRoute: Pages.home,
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        WidgetBuilder builder;
        // Manage your route names here
        switch (settings.name) {
          case Pages.home:
            builder = (BuildContext context) => _page1();
            break;
          case Pages.page1:
            builder = (BuildContext context) => _page1();
            break;
          case Pages.page2:
            builder = (BuildContext context) => _page2();
            break;
          case Pages.page3:
            builder = (BuildContext context) => _page3();
            break;
          case Pages.page4:
            builder = (BuildContext context) => Page4Screen(navigatorKey: navigationKey);
            break;
          default:
            throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
        }
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: builder,
          settings: settings,
       );
      },
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(),
    ...
  );
}
```

#### Demo

[image: Demo]

#### Minimal Repro

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Nested Routing Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class Pages{
  static const home = '/';
  static const page1 = '/page1';
  static const page2 = '/page2';
  static const page3 = '/page3';
  static const page4 = '/page4';
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<HomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigationKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  var _currentPage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Navigator(
        key: navigationKey,
        initialRoute: '/',
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          WidgetBuilder builder;
          // Manage your route names here
          switch (settings.name) {
            case Pages.home:
              builder = (BuildContext context) => _page1();
              break;
            case Pages.page1:
              builder = (BuildContext context) => _page1();
              break;
            case Pages.page2:
              builder = (BuildContext context) => _page2();
              break;
            case Pages.page3:
              builder = (BuildContext context) => _page3();
              break;
            case Pages.page4:
              builder = (BuildContext context) => Page4Screen(navigatorKey: navigationKey);
              break;
            default:
              throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
          }
          // You can also return a PageRouteBuilder and
          // define custom transitions between pages
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: builder,
            settings: settings,
          );
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.mood),
            label: 'Page 1',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.connect_without_contact),
            label: 'Page 2',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.message),
            label: 'Page 3',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _currentPage,
        // selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: (value) {
          /// Update page if a different tab from the current was clicked
          if (value != _currentPage)
            setState(() {
              _currentPage = value;
              switch (value) {
                case 0:
                  navigationKey.currentState!
                      .pushReplacementNamed(Pages.page1);
                  break;
                case 1:
                  navigationKey.currentState!
                      .pushReplacementNamed(Pages.page2);
                  break;
                case 2:
                  navigationKey.currentState!
                      .pushReplacementNamed(Pages.page3);
                  break;
                default:

                /// TODO Error 404 page
                  throw Exception('Invalid route: $value');
              }
            });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _page1() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Page 1'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _page2() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.orangeAccent,
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Page2'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _page3() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Page 3'),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
                navigationKey.currentState!.pushNamed(Pages.page4);
              }, child: Text('Page 4')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page4Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  Page4Screen({Key? key, required GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey}) : _navigatorKey = navigatorKey, super(key: key);
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey;
  @override
  createState() => Page4State();
}

class Page4State extends State<Page4Screen>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // appBar: AppBar(
      //   title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.txtTitleMood),
      //   automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      // ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.redAccent,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Page 4'),ElevatedButton(
                // Within the SecondScreen widget
                onPressed: () {
                  // Navigate back to the first screen by popping the current route
                  // off the stack.
                  widget._navigatorKey.currentState!.pop();
                },
                child: Text('Go Back!'),
              ),
            ],
          ),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're using ``pushReplacementNamed`` which will override the route.

Comment: Use ``pushNamed`` instead.

Comment: @OMiShah I use `pushNamed` to navigate to Page 4. You can see this on `Widget _page3()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Navigator` widget does not handle back buttons by default and that's your job to do it if you have defined a `Navigator` widget. You can catch back press by `WillPopScope` widget. It takes a `Future<bool> Function()` which will be called whenever user wants to go back. If it returns false then your default `Navigator` which lies in `MaterialApp` will not pop the current route which simply is showing your `HomePage` in this case. So if your nested navigator has something to pop (like `Page4`) then it will pop that and will prevent your main `Navigator` from popping your `HomePage`.

```
class _HomeState extends State<HomePage> {
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => !(await navigationKey.currentState!.maybePop()),
      child: Scaffold(
        ...
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `navigationKey.currentState!.maybePop()` returns true on initial app start. Why is that? This results to this beahvior:

![Demo willPop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpHxO.gif) ![Demo willPop navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDWXo.gif)

Comment: Are you sure you're using the exact code I've written? cause I'm testing it and it's working correctly. Don't forget about the not operator (!). @Omatt

Comment: I found the issue. It looks like `initialRoute` should be set to `'/'`. If `initialRoute` has a name set i.e. `'/route'`, navigator returns currentState.maybePop() as true. I tested it again and the code now works as expected. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. BTW I've never tested it that way. Good to know. @Omatt